# redirection all https requests to http

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, https

Small problem here, before changing my site to CMS, I have encountered a problem with redirecting all `https://` requests to `http://`.

I have had the following in my `.htaccess`, which was doing all that

```
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.net/$1 [L,R=301]
```

but after changing it to CMS that requires different setup, I can no longer use the above mentioned code, since it does not do what it was intended to do in the first place.

Here is my current setup from `.htaccess`

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L,NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)mysite\.net$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.net/$1 [L,R=301]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mysite.net/.*$ [NC]
 RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|tif|js|css|xls|xlsx|zip|rar|pdf|ods|ots)$ - [F]
```

Can you please advise me on how to do it all correctly, since I really do not want to double up all site content because of this problem and would rather redirect it all to the one consistent protocol.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your .htaccess like this:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ http://www.mysite.net%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https [OR]
 RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
 RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mysite.net/.*$ [NC]
 RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|tif|js|css|xls|xlsx|zip|rar|pdf|ods|ots)$ - [F,NC]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Try this in Firebug and see whether you are getting 301 or not. Further create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then open `https://mysite.net/info.php` to check what is its `DOCUMENT_ROOT` value.

Comment: the document root value is /var/www/vhosts/mysite.net/httpdocs

Comment: Is it exactly same as `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of http site? Did you get 301 in Firebug?

Comment: I have tried with firebug, but it is not 301ing instead it gives 403 on css file and when I try with https:// it is redirecting with no end

Comment: it is exactly the same DOCUMENT_ROOT

Comment: try edited code, I will be offline for few hours and check back in couple of hours.

Comment: THanks for trying but nothing worked, I have no idea as to what is going on on that setup

Comment: Any other suggestions, since nothing had worked so far

Comment: I have provided solutions that where all working fine (and have worked for other folks also). TO debug further your problem you can enable rewrite log on your end and provide me output of that.

Comment: Your solution worked, it was in conflict with other rules, but I got rid of them. One question, what it now does is simply redirects all https:// to http://, but should it not give warning first to let user know that the site is actually using a certificate?

Comment: Certificate negotiation happens outside rewrite rule module and warning is issued only if certificate is invalid.